# Simple Excel SUMIF not working?

Tags: excel, formula

is seems too basic. But after spending quite some time on the web, I don't see where the problem lies... I have two columns, O and S, with some numeric values. I want to add values in column S only if the data in column O are larger than "-9999". Now, the formula should be:

=SUMIF(O2:O23, ">-9999", S2:S23)

But Excel (Mac 2011) tells me that this is wrong. Where lies the problem?

Thanks for any hints!

Edit: [Here](http://www.pic-upload.de/view-17952745/Screen-Shot-2013-02-01-at-10.54.25.png.html) is a screenshot. And [here](http://geodev.grid.unep.ch/download/GEO_Data_Portal__gdp_ppp__1359710118.xls) the Excel file.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? It works for me in Excel 2011

Comment: "The formula you typed contains an error."

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? Like I said, it works just fine for me

Comment: Here is mine :) http://wikisend.com/download/536100/Untitled.png

Comment: What are your regional settings? If you are in continental Europe you probably need ; in place of , so try `=SUMIF(O2:O23; ">-9999"; S2:S23)`

Comment: Yep, great. That was it! Thanks so much. Wonna post it as answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comment you probably need to replace commas in the formula with semi-colons, i.e.

`=SUMIF(O2:O23; ">-9999"; S2:S23)`

"separators" used in formulas change based on regional settings - UK and US use commas, continental Europe typically uses semi-colons